# What's the name of this equality axiom?

Tags: arithmetic, axioms

For ***any*** numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, the **transitive property** of equality states that if $a=b$ and $b=c$, then $a=c$. In a slight variation, for ***any*** numbers $a$ and $c$, and for ***some*** number $b$, then $a=b$ and $b=c$ if and only if $a=c$. Is there a special name for this property?

Comment: What is the alternative form? "for some"? The "for all" version implies the "for some" one: thus, no need of a specific name.

Comment: The main form could be translated as $\forall a\forall b \forall c[a=b \land b=c \rightarrow a=c]$ and the variation as $\forall a \forall c[ \exists b [a=b \land b=c] \leftrightarrow a=c]$. The variation introduces an adittional implication.

Comment: What is the benefit? if $a=c$ then it is enough to consider $b=a=c$ and the implication holds.

Comment: I thought the implication $a=c \rightarrow \exists b [a=b \land b=c]$ was not considered part of the transitive property.

Comment: If you have an empty set, then you can have the equality relation without any such $b$.  So it is not an inherent property of equality.

Comment: @Henry - on the empty set, $\forall a \forall c[ \exists b [a=b \land b=c] \leftrightarrow a=c]$ still holds vacuously. But as Mauro has indicated, it is a trivial corrolary of the transitive property anyway.